# networkx: shortest path returning a list of edge weights along that path

Tags: python, networkx

I want to find the shortest path between nodes `A` and `Z` in a networkx `MultiDiGraph` and have a list of edge weights along this path.

I can find the shortest path using `networkx.shortest_path(G, source=A, target=Z, weight="factor")`, which returns a list of nodes in that path, for example `[A, B, ..., Z]`. But I am more interested in the edge weights (specifically the one called 'factor') along that path.

Ultimately I will need to multiply these edges.

Is there a built-in function in networkx which returns a list of edges along the shortest path?

Comment: it seems (to me) like all the shortest path functions in networkx only return a list of nodes making up the shortest path, but not a list of edges between those nodes in the shortest path. The latter is what I am after.... I COULD look up the edge between each successive pair of nodes in that shortest path, and keep track of the encoutered weights, but it seems like this functionality is hidden somewhere in networkx.... All I'm trying to do is not re-invent the wheel...

Comment: The output of the function makes sense to me. Besides, all you want is a trivial derivative of said output. But feel free to look at the source code and further helper functions called therein. I've ended up at [this](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/algorithms/shortest_paths/weighted.html#multi_source_dijkstra), which seems to compute the weighted sum from one node to another intermediate node and if a newer smaller sum if founded, the node path is updated. But it doesn't store the edge list because it's superfluous information.

Comment: I guess it's superfluous according to the application at hand. It's not immediately obvious to me why the list of nodes in the shortest path would be of greater importance than the list of edges in the shortest path.... design choice I guess. Nonetheless, I need the product of weights along the shortest path. There exists the `path_weight` function, which *almost* does what I need, except it takes the sum rather than the product...https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.path_weight.html

Comment: If I were to guess, it's because the list of edges requires to be stored as tuples, i.e., (A, B), (B, C), (C, D), which be shortened to A, B, C, D, which is the list of nodes. A quick search for product of weighted edges in networkx didn't result in anything implemented in the library already. So you may actually have to _invent_ the wheel.